# Flutter Spinner date picker (CupertinoDatePicker) change order/swap location

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use Spinner date picker but I did not find it in flutter packages I found something similar
[CupertinoDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html) which works fine.

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

but I can't change the order of the date or dateFormat,
example the default here  is `month-day-year` I want to change it to `day-month-year`, also to change month words September,October to numbers 9,10
I know I can do this using localization but isn't there **a way to force it to change for all** ?
I found [DatePickerDateOrder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/DatePickerDateOrder-class.html) which says :

> Determines the order of the columns inside CupertinoDatePicker in date mode.

which suppose to change the order `dmy →  12 | March | 1996` but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: `dateOrder: DatePickerDateOrder.dmy`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [flutter_cupertino_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker#-readme-tab)

```dart
DatePicker.showDatePicker(
    context,
    maxDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    dateFormat:'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
);
```

Comment: yeah I saw this before, I wanted a way to force it to change using DatePickerDateOrder

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to specify

```
dateOrder: DatePickerDateOrder.dmy
```